# Lightning component: List view base component display problems

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I used List View [base component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation) in my lightning component, everything works fine besides display issues when inline editing User lookup when editing last record in a list. Below screens shows the issue:

[image: List without edit]
[image: List during edit]
[image: Where the users are]

Ase you can see there is possibility to select users but someone would need to know that he need to scroll down, and when there is only one record it's extremely irritating to actually do that.

I tried to override standard list view styles but I failed miserably. Anyone faced maybe this issue?